# JWT Spring auth login user

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat, jwt

I'm using JWT Spring security in my web application to authenticate user login. For server on my local machine i'm using tomcat. MySQL database. So when I start server, login with some user then I go to database and change password of that user. Than I logout and try again to login with new password it throws me error that password is incorrect. I login with old password and it works. But when I restart tomcat than I can login only with new password. Here's my CustomUserDetailService.

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;

    private User user = null;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Object[] account = userDao.findByUserName(username);
        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        this.user =  new User(
                (String) account[0], 
                (String) account[1], 
                enabled, 
                accountNonExpired, 
                credentialsNonExpired, 
                accountNonLocked,
                getAuthorities((String)account[2])
        );

        return this.user;
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(String role) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(role));
        return authList;
    }

    public List<String> getRoles(String role) {
        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();
            roles.add(role);
        return roles;
    }

    public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (String role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
        return authorities;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have started your tomcat server, it is still referencing the previous database and a local copy in memory. Hence a fresh build is recommended anytime you make database changes so that the server is not referencing an older copy.

That is the reason you get an error for the password. Make sure you update the core edmx file anytime you make database changes.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand that. Where can I find that edmx file? I'm using java spring jwt with mysql database.